# Save() not saving nested properties

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new in mongo. I need to update one nested field in MongoDB model. This is my code: -

```
const employee = await empModel.searchData(Query);

countryArray.push({lang: 'eng', result 100});

countryArray.push({lang: 'german', result 99});

employee[0].country = countryArray;

employee[0].markModified('country');

employee[0].save();
```

Schema of empModel:

```
onst mongoSchema = new Schema({
  empId: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  }],
  country:[{
    lang:String,
    result:Number
  }],
  projectId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

Comment: What is `countryArray`? Which field do you want to update? Could you explain what you needed

Comment: i need to update 'country' field with 'countryArray'. countryArray is an array which has updated value that i need to save in db

Comment: Have you taken `countryArray` field in the schema? And if you want to update the document then use simple use update query instead of finding and then update..

Comment: I have country field, but i need to replace country field value by countryArray value

Comment: Show the code for `searchData` function as well

Comment: static async searchData(query) {
    const searchData = await this.find(query);

    return searchData;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple update query instead of find and the update

```
static async updateData(query, countryArray) {
  const updateData= await this.update(query, { $set: { country: countryArray }});  
  console.log(updated successfully')
  return 'Updated successfully'
}

const countryArray = []
countryArray.push({lang: 'eng', result 100})
countryArray.push({lang: 'german', result 99})
const update = await empModel.updateData(Query, countryArray)
```